# How to add onChange or any kind of event to mdl-selectfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add a `onChange` or any kind of event to the `mdl-selectfield`.

I have a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ad7rqt8g/1/

```html
      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css'>
      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/kybarg/mdl-selectfield/mdl-menu-implementation/mdl-selectfield.min.css'>
      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <form>
      <div class="mdl-selectfield mdl-js-selectfield">
        <select class="mdl-selectfield__select" id="professsion1" name="professsion" onChange="alert(this.value);">
          <option value="option1">option 1</option>
          <option value="option2">option 2</option>
          <option value="option3">option 3</option>
          <option value="option4">option 4</option>
          <option value="option5">option 5</option>
        </select>
        <label class="mdl-selectfield__label" for="professsion1">Profession</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  <script src='https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/kybarg/mdl-selectfield/mdl-menu-implementation/mdl-selectfield.min.js'></script>
```

I add it and it doesnt alert any kind of value on change. I reasearched on github and people had simmilar issues but no fix.
Thank you for your replies in advance

Comment: The problem is your `mdl-selectfield.min.js` file. Though minimized it has it's own bindings to the `change` event which most likely is preventing propagation and processes it's own code.

Comment: does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: As I said, `mdl-selectfield.min.js` has its own `change` event code. You have to get the un-minimized version so you can see what it does and if it is as simple as propagation being stopped, change that code and use your own custom version of `mdl-selectfield.min.js`

Comment: There is an alternate version of `mdl-selectfield` which properly bubbles events. I updated your fiddle using that here https://jsfiddle.net/h5p8vwok/ I think it uses this version https://github.com/MEYVN-digital/mdl-selectfield

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you can use `.off()` in combination with `.on()` to unbind from the event which is bound in the JS file.

Something like..

```
$(function() {
    .off('change', '#professsion1')
    .on('change', '#professsion1', function () {
      alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: If you unbind all events from the dropdown you unbind the code intended to run to begin with. So your alert might show but the dropdown is no longer working as intended. Sadly the needed code also prevents event bubbling. There is a version of the same plugin with proper event bubbling.

Comment: This wouldn't unbind all all events, it would only unbind the click event. Also my answer does answer the initial question of "How do I add onChange event" so not sure why it deserves a -1

Comment: Sorry, should have been specific, you would unbind all `change` events from the `select` element which is what the plugin binds to as well using the `change` event. Also, in general, even if you would not unbind the plugin, using script bindings instead of inline still doesn't work as the change event is not bubble up by the plug-in. You can test it using OPs fiddle as well.

Comment: Ah right I see what you mean now. Tried it in the fiddle and you are correct. Thanks for the info